# SpinBoxDelegate displayed as a DoubleSpinBoxDelegate

Tags: c++, qt, delegates, qwidget

I've created a `SpinBoxDelegate` for a tableView. When i edit a integer value(QVariant) in the Table the `editorWidget` behaves like a `QDoubleSpinbox` even though it is a `QSpinBox`.

I'm using `QT 5.5.1` not the current Version and i took the code for the delegate from the [Qt Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-spinboxdelegate-example.html)

```
QWidget *SpinBoxDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent,
                                   const QStyleOptionViewItem &/* option 
*/,
                                   const QModelIndex &/* index */) const
{
QSpinBox *editor = new QSpinBox(parent);
editor->setFrame(false);
/*editor->setMinimum(0);
editor->setMaximum(100);*/

return editor;
}

void SpinBoxDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor,
                                const QModelIndex &index) const
{
int value = index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toInt();

QSpinBox *spinBox = static_cast<QSpinBox*>(editor);
spinBox->setValue(value);
}

void SpinBoxDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,
                               const QModelIndex &index) const
{
QSpinBox *spinBox = static_cast<QSpinBox*>(editor);
spinBox->interpretText();
int value = spinBox->value();

model->setData(index, value, Qt::EditRole);
}
```

I want that the displayed widget has no decimals.

This was the code causing the trouble... Since the value in the QVariant was no integer but a double i never allocated the delegate...

```
for(int col = 1; col < mModel->columnCount() ;col++){
    QVariant::Type colType = mModel->data(mModel->index(0,col), Qt::DisplayRole).type();
    switch(colType){
        case QVariant::Int:
            ui->tableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(col, sbDelegate);
            break;
        case QVariant::String:
            break;
        case QVariant::Double:
            break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is seemingly nothing wrong with your delegate. Please compare my posted solution carefully with your own code. For the future it would be helpful to create  reproducible minimal examples.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include "SpinboxDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    QApplication app(argc, args);
    auto tableView = new QTableView;
    auto model=new QStandardItemModel;
    model->setRowCount(2);
    model->setColumnCount(2);
    tableView->setModel(model);
    tableView->setItemDelegate(new SpinBoxDelegate);
    tableView->show();
    app.exec();
}
```

**SpinboxDelegate.h**

```
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

class SpinBoxDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &, const QModelIndex & ) const;
    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const;
};
```

**SpinboxDelegate.cpp**

```
#include "SpinboxDelegate.h"

#include <QSpinBox>

QWidget *SpinBoxDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent,
                                   const QStyleOptionViewItem &/* option 
*/,
                                   const QModelIndex &/* index */) const
{
QSpinBox *editor = new QSpinBox(parent);
editor->setFrame(false);
/*editor->setMinimum(0);
editor->setMaximum(100);*/

return editor;
}

void SpinBoxDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor,
                                const QModelIndex &index) const
{
int value = index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toInt();

QSpinBox *spinBox = static_cast<QSpinBox*>(editor);
spinBox->setValue(value);
}

void SpinBoxDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,
                               const QModelIndex &index) const
{
QSpinBox *spinBox = static_cast<QSpinBox*>(editor);
spinBox->interpretText();
int value = spinBox->value();

model->setData(index, value, Qt::EditRole);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. I get the data for the table from a database and somehw the values weren't stored as integers but as floats with no precision... Thus my delegate was never used and istead it was the standard delegate...